# SQL : How Use max function in 1 record

Tags: mysql, database

My table here. (tb_mo)

```
mid     |  g1  |  g2  |  g3  |  g4  |

001   **|  121 |  20  |  101 |  95  |**  <----- this record i want to use MAX().
002     |  41  |  112 |  25  |  54  |
```

I just want to use MAX() to this Record only, to find MAX value from g1 to g4 and show MAX value. And show result like this.

g1  |
121 |

I want to use this on php. Or someone have better way.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I dont know if you can do that with mysql, but in t-sql I have a split_string function that I create and it returns a table. So I can do something like this: select max(value) from dbo.split_string('001 | 121 | 20 | 101 | 95','|').  But like I said id dont know if you can make functions like that in mysql.

Comment: the MAX() function returns the biggest column in a set of rows, if you want to get the greatest value form a set of values (a set of columns in one row for example) you need to use GREATEST() as the answer explains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `GREATEST()` which gets the highest value in a row. eg.

```
SELECT GREATEST(g1,g2,g3,g4) highestValue
FROM tableName
// WHERE  ...your conditions here...
```

Comment: Can i show g1 column ? because i must to use columns name too.

Comment: It's can use. But I want any more answer,Because i'm just a new guy.